# WordPress HTTP Request with null bytes?

Tags: wordpress, http

Consider this WordPress code:

```
    if ( intval( $form_id ) === $postform ) {
    $jsondata = json_encode( $form_data_array );
    $postdata = [
        'method'      => 'POST',
        'timeout'     => 60,
        'httpversion' => '1.1',
        'blocking'    => false,
        'headers'     => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Expect' => '',
        ],
        'sslverify'   => true,
        'body'        => $jsondata,
        'data_format' => 'body',
    ];
    $response = wp_remote_post( $postto, $postdata );
```

The code appears to run correctly, with the `$jsondata` being approximate 60k characters in size, but on the receiving side when reading the data it starts with `{"fields":`, ends with '}', but approximately 40k of the bytes preceding the ending `}` are null bytes.

`$form_data_array` was passed directly with the same behavior, the `{"fields":` prefix, the '}' suffix at the end, but roughly the last 2/3 of the data prior to the suffix was `0`/null bytes.

Is there some limit buried in the serialization of the HTTP body that is causing the null bytes? It's almost as if some part of the code knows how long the total string should be, but some string copy is not moving all of the data into the final string.

If there is such a limit, what is it, and how can it be configured?

Answer (score 0):

I had to mess around with this, it took me a bunch of experimenting with various options to get this to go.

This works utterly reliably for me, for posting JSON data from one WordPress server to a REST endpoint on another (telemetry upload for a plugin).

```php
  $payload = json_encode( $stats );
  $options = [
    'body'        => $payload,
    'headers'     => [
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'timeout'     => 60,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'blocking'    => false,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'sslverify'   => false,
    'data_format' => 'body',
  ];

  $result = wp_remote_post( $target, $options );
```

I don't have the Expect header, I use http 1.0, and I don't demand sslverify. My JSON objects are generally 100KiB or more in size. You might try this combo.

But if it works and your's doesn't, I sure don't know why. Maybe somebody?